# PHP/MySQL-code cut off when storing in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update some fields in a MySQL database. These fields contain PHP- and HTML-code. I am aware of the fact that this is dangerous. However the application is running on the Intranet and therefore I don't want to trouble this discussion.
 
My problem is that it seems impossible (for me) to get the code in the database. Part of the string is truncated. Part of my code (in which the problem occurs) is as follows:

```
$sql = ("UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `code` = '<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='http://URL?rel=0&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>') WHERE `table`.`id` =4 LIMIT 1 ;");
```

The problem starts with the first '<' of the first 'iframe'. Everything behind it is not interpreted when running it. When I replace the code with a word, i.e. 'test', the code is interpreted correctly and saves well.

Thanks very much for any help to solve this.
Rob

Comment: I assume you have escaped the single quotes in your content since replacing iframe with test works. WHere are you viewing the saved data?

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the apostrophs inside your HTML code

```
$sql = ("UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `code` = '<iframe width=\'100%\' height=\'100%\' src=\'http://URL?rel=0&autoplay=1\' frameborder=\'0\' allowfullscreen></iframe>') WHERE `table`.`id` =4 LIMIT 1 ;";
```

or a little bit simpler:

```
$sql = ("UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `code` = \"<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='http://URL?rel=0&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>\") WHERE `table`.`id` =4 LIMIT 1 ;";
```

also, the paranthesys looks wrong:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `code` = \"<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='http://URL?rel=0&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>\" WHERE `table`.`id` =4 LIMIT 1 ;";
```

Comment: It's weird that the DB doesn't warn, isn't it? But this should do the trick, 1 up.

Comment: Thanks for the really quick response. 
I used the 2nd solution of Tudor. That worked best for me. So case closed.

Have fun,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Using function htmlentities()

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now"

$a = htmlentities($orig);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now;
```

And  html_entity_decode()

```
$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```